# Translate a GeometryGroup in OptiX

Tags: nvidia, raytracing

I am using NVIDIA's OptiX ray-tracing engine.

I want o know how can I translate the position of a GeometryGroup (or its instances) during rendering.

From the samples I see how I can translate the entire scene (using the middle-button). But I want to translate a single model/geometry group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing this code, it translates the first geometric model:

```
void updateObjectPos(float dX, float dY, float dZ)
{
    // we have only one group - the main group whose childs are instances of Transform
    // mainGroup is an instance of Group
    Transform t = mainGroup->getChild<Transform>(0);
    float m[16];
    t->getMatrix(false, m, NULL);
    m[3] += dX;
    m[7] += dY;
    m[11]+= dZ;
    t->setMatrix(false, m, NULL);

    // mark dirty so that the acceleration structure gets rebuilt
    mainGroup->getAcceleration()->markDirty();
}
```

Comment: which optix version are you using? I tried this with optix 3.8, but it did not work. Do you know how to transform the objects using the new optix?

Comment: @mmostajab sorry, I don't. If I recall correctly this was OptiX 2.x